# How to apply pulltorefresh feature to PagewiseListView in Flutter?

Tags: listview, pagination, flutter

Flutter code issue: I want to create pagination in listview. I successfully achieved it using PagewiseListview. But now I want to add PulltoRefresh in my PagewiseListView using package 'pull_to_refresh'. My code snippet is below.

I want to wrap PagewiseListView in SmartRefresher. For time being, I used RefreshIndicator.

```
class PagewiseListViewExample extends State<ListPage> {
  static const int PAGE_SIZE = 10;
  final GlobalKey<RefreshIndicatorState> _refreshIndicatorKey =
      GlobalKey<RefreshIndicatorState>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
        super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Pagination'), centerTitle: true),
        body: RefreshIndicator(
            onRefresh: refreshData,
            child: PagewiseListView(
                errorBuilder: (context, error) {
                  return Text(error);
                },
                showRetry: false,
                loadingBuilder: (context) {
                  return LinearProgressIndicator(
                    backgroundColor: Colors.green,
                  );
                },
                key: _refreshIndicatorKey,
                pageSize: PAGE_SIZE,
                    itemBuilder: this._itemBuilder,
                pageFuture: (pageIndex) => BackendService.getPosts(
                pageIndex * PAGE_SIZE, PAGE_SIZE))));
  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To refresh work properly, you'll need to wrap your pageview widget inside a ListView widget.

You can only use the refresh indicator correctly if the child of it, it's a scrollable widget.

Comment: So , is it not possible for PagewiseListview.

Comment: I think it's because of the scroll axis, which in this case it's horizontal